# Function on an open interval

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the function $f:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for which:
$$\forall x \in (a,b):f(x)=\sup_{t>x}f(t)=\inf_{t<x}f(t)$$

is a decreasing continuous function on $(a,b)$.

I've already proved that it's decreasing.

Since requested:
$$\forall x \in (a,b) \forall y \in (a,b):(x<y \Rightarrow f(x)>f(y)$$

Assume $x<y$. Then f(x)>f(y) iff:
$$\inf_{t<x}f(t)>\inf_{t<y}f(t)$$

And this is true, since $t<x$ is a subset of $t<y$ so its $\inf$ must be larger.

Comment: Please post your proof that $f$ is decreasing to show your commission to the task.

Answer (score 0):

### Hint

Prove
$$\lim_{h \searrow 0} f(x+h) = \lim_{h \nearrow 0} f(x+h) \qquad \forall x\in(a,b)$$